# Checking String and an Array of Strings in Java

Tags: java, string

I am stuck with an issue . I am calling a method A() . Which sometimes return String and sometimes it returns Array of Strings (String[] strArr) . How can I handle that scenario programmatically ? I don't have any control in the return type of the method A() .

I have to call that method and store the returned value in a variable. The type of the variable needs to be fixed depending upon the returned value (String / Array of Strings) from the method .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: What is the signature of A()?

Comment: What is the signature of this method?

Comment: You can use `instanceof` operator.

Comment: What is the return type of A() ? How one method will allow two return types?

Comment: Both cases you should get Array of string, but in one Array will contain only one element. Return type will be Array of Strings, indeed.

Comment: Are you not getting compiler error for incorrect definition of method A() ? How can a method return two types ?

Comment: I guess that the return type is Object :  `private Object getValue() { return condition() ? "" : new String[]{ "" }; }`

Comment: To avoid all these comments, please add an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Everyone will save time

Comment: I have values in JCR Node . If user enters single value , then , it will be a single valued String in JCR node . If more than one value is entered, then it will be an Array of Strings .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
Object returnedValue = A();
if (returnedValue instanceof String)
{
    ...
}
else if (returnedValue instanceof String[])
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is what I was expecting for .. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would rather suggest change in signature of A().  The method A() should always return String[] and at the calling end check for the length of the array and perform necessary action.

Comment: I agree with you. An API should be clear, the user should not have to cast the result.